# Mousedown on parent trigger click event on child elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'm working on the slider with swipe effect. I'm using the example from the Youtube tutorial by Wes Bos. The problem is when I click on the parent (mousedown event) it triggers the child event too, after the mouseup event.

I tried to add the timer which will allow clicking event on the child elements, a few seconds after the mouseup event is finished.

HTML:

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.items {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.items .item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background: green;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Javascript:

```
let clickNotAllowed = false;

// ------------------- Tutorial ------------------- //
const slider = document.getElementsByClassName('items')[0];
let isDown = false;
let startY;
let scrollTop;
let speed = 0.5;


// Mouse down will trigger the parent event (swipe), but also the child event will
// be added to the list of events which need to be executed
slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  startY = e.pageY - slider.offsetTop;
  scrollTop = slider.scrollTop;
});

slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDown = false;
  clickNotAllowed = false;
});

slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;

  // Not part of the tutorial
  // I tried to set the timer so a few ms after the mouse is up
  // I'm setting the clickNotAllowed to true so the user will be able to click
  // Before this timer is finished, click event on the child will try to execute itself
  setTimeout(function() {
    clickNotAllowed = false;
  }, 200);

});

slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {

  if(!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageY - slider.offsetTop;
  const walk = (x - startY) * speed;
  slider.scrollTop = scrollTop - walk;

  // --- Not part of tutorial --- //
  clickNotAllowed = true;

});

// ============= NOT PART OF THE TUTORIAL ============= //
const item = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

for(let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {

    item[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    if(clickNotAllowed) return;

    e.target.style.background = "blue";

  });

}
```

The expected result is when I click on the parent (slider - items class) and mousedown event is fired, child event should not be executed after the mouseup for parent element is executed.

Comment: This type of behavior is usually solved by adding `event.stopPropagation()` to you click-eventListener

Comment: Please check this example I made. https://jsfiddle.net/y4x0ophn/3/
I added `event.stopPropagation()` but the child event is fired.

Comment: Checkout the fiddle, and you can add `pointer-events: none;` to `.swiper__item`. The problem is there because you automatically drag around images.

Comment: The problem is if I add this code click event will be completely removed from the item. But I need it because I want to open the image when I click on it.
Basically, this is a slider for image gallery. 
https://jsfiddle.net/jvs34amq/4/